# C/C++ georeferenced plots?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, latitude-longitude

I'm searching for the most suitable C/C++ library offering a set of tools (functions) able of plotting on georeferenced images (data). Specifically these tools should be alble of working in geographical latitude, longitude coordinates.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Blue marble geographics](http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/) sell SDKs for this type of thing, though they can be expensive and have run-time royalties.

Comment: Your link is very interesting. However I was searching for a free library. Is there anyone that can give any suggestions? Thank you for your time